# Overpass Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint Flag

Tags: c++, qt, qml, flags, foreground

I am facing a problem with the `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`.

I am developing an application that when launched needs to be on the foreground and over any other application. In order to do that in my `Window` `QML` file I set the flag `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`.

However, in my `C++` code, I use a `QFileDialog`, again with the `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag. When I click on the button that should make the `QFileDialog` appear, the `QFileDialog` is correctly created but stays under my `Window`.

Does someone know how to set a `QFileDialog` to appears correctly over a `QML Window` with the `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the parent of the `QFileDialog`? Normally a `QDialog` should be drawn on top of the top-most widget of its parent (provided is has one).

Comment: Initially it had no parent, but I tried setting the QML Window as its parent and it still does not work as it should.

Comment: What if you unset the flag for the main window for as long as the dialog is open?

Comment: Well, the problem is that my "app" is launched from another, already ,existing one (I am upgrading applications from flex to Qt and doing app by app) . I don't have acces to the source code of the first app and it probably has a flag setting it up as Main Window so most of the time when i launch my app it stays under the main one. That's why unsetting the flag is not really possible. Looks like it was a known bug for mac : [QTBUG-36178](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36178)